# avoid parsing last separator with `sepBy`

Tags: parsing, haskell, megaparsec

I'm trying to parse a string using `megaparsec`.

Part of it is a repetition of strings separated by a separator and I'm using `sepBy` for this.
Consider for example

```
sepBy (char 'a') (char 's')
```

This parses correctly `""`, `"a"`, `"asa"`, ...
The problem appears if I need to continue parsing with another parser which starts with my separator, as in

```
(,) <$> sepBy (char 'a') (char 's') <*> string "something"
```

If I try to parse the string `"asasomething"` with this parser I'd expect to get `("aa", "something")`. Instead I get an error because I don't have an `a` after the second `s`.

I tried also with `sepEndBy` but the result is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it as follows.

The implementation of `sepBy` used by `megapersec` is

```
sepBy :: MonadPlus m => m a -> m sep -> m [a]
sepBy p sep = do
  r <- C.optional p
  case r of
    Nothing -> return []
    Just  x -> (x:) <$> many (sep >> p)
```

I modified it to

```
sepBy :: Parser a -> Parser sep -> Parser [a]
sepBy p sep = do
  r <- optional p
  case r of
    Nothing -> return []
    Just  x -> (x:) <$> many (try $ sep >> p)
```

to specialise it to `Parsec` add a `try` to avoid eager parsing